# How do I make the eyes symmetrical?

Tags: objects, axis

My model has two shaded separate object eyeballs inside the head. The one on the right is ok but how do I get the left one to match the opposite on the x axis?[image]

Comment: Would Mirroring be possible? Are the eyes the same mesh?

Comment: Move it? What's wrong with placing an object where you want it?

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading - it sounds as if the eyes themselves were not symmetrical, but it seems they are just not placed symmetrical in the head. Unfortunately I can't see in the screenshot if the face is symmetrical on the scene's X axis. If so, since the eyes look like they are identical, you could simply go to the location values of the correct eye, copy the X value and paste it as X value on the incorrect eye. Then simply make it a negative or positive value (well, the opposite of what the original value was).

Comment: Your solution worked for me I can't believe I didn't think of that sooner. Also, I didn't realize my question was typed somewhat incorrectly I was a bit tired that time, so I probably didn't check it properly.